# Is it possible to use command line as a client to remote debugging a Java project?

Tags: java, remote-debugging

Normally we use eclipse/IntellijIdea to remote debugging a Java application. I wonder is it possible to use some command line tool to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

To local debug you can use [jdb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html).

Bear in mind that your remote java process must be started with parameters to enable debug.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one example:

Run you Java application from command line:

> java
>   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=localhost:8000 -cp $CLASSPATH com.company.YourJavaClass

In another command line window, run:

> jdb -attach localhost:8000

Then you could also set breakpoint by using the:

- `stop at MyClass:22` (sets a breakpoint at the first instruction for
  line 22 of the source file containing MyClass)
- `stop in
  java.lang.String.length` (sets a breakpoint at the beginnig of the
  method java.lang.String.length)
- `stop in MyClass.<init>` (
  identifies the MyClass constructor)
- `stop in MyClass.<clinit>`
  ( identifies the static initialization code for MyClass)

and use either `step` or `next` command to "step in" or "step through"